# How can I select all text within an element in scrapy if said element has other elements inside?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I've got a page with sections like this. It is basically a single question within the main p tag, but every time there are certain superscripts, it breaks my code.

The text I want to get is - "For Cosine Rule of any triangle ABC, b2 is equal to"

```
<p><span class="mcq_srt">MCQ.</span>For Cosine Rule of any triangle ABC, b<sup>2</sup> is equal to</p>
    <ol>
        <li>a<sup>2</sup> - c<sup>2</sup> + 2ab cos A</li>
        <li>a<sup>3</sup> + c<sup>3</sup> - 3ab cos A</li>
        <li>a<sup>2</sup> + c<sup>2</sup> - 2ac cos B</li>
        <li>a<sup>2</sup> - c<sup>2</sup> 4bc cos A</li>
    </ol>
```

When I try to do a select for the p, I miss out the 2 that are supposed to be super-scripted. Further, I also get two sentences in the list, which messes up a few things when I try to store the answers

```
 response.css('p::text') > ["For Cosine Rule of any triangle ABC, b", "is equal to"]
```

I could tried a select using

```
response.css('p sup::text')
```

and then try merging it by checking if a sentence ever started with a small letter but that messed up when I had many questions. Here's what I'm doing in my parse method

```
`
    questions = [x for x in questions if x not in [' ']] #The list I get usually has a bunch of ' ' in them
    question_sup = response.css('p sup::text').extract()
    answer_sup = response.css('li sup::text').extract()
    all_choices = response.css('li::text')[:-2].extract() #for choice
    all_answer = response.css('.dsplyans::text').extract() #for answer

    if len(question_sup) is not 0:
        count=-1
        for question in questions:
            if question[1].isupper() is False or question[0] in [',', '.']: #[1] because there is a space at the starting
                questions[count]+=question_sup.pop(0)+question
                del questions[count+1]

            count+=1
```

What I tried above fails quite a bunch of times, and I have no idea how I can debug it. I'm crawling quite a lot of pages, and I have no Idea how to debug this. I keep getting a cannot pop empty list error. I guess, that's because something is wrong with what I'm trying above. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

If you select all the elements with text within the `p`, including the `p` itself, you will get a list of text nodes that respect the order, so you can simply join the list with `''`. Here:

```
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> p = Selector(text='<p>For Cosine Rule of any triangle ABC, b<sup>2</sup> is equal to</p>')
>>> t = p.css('p::text, p *::text')  # Give me the text in <p>, plus the text of all of its descendants
>>> ''.join(t.extract())
'For Cosine Rule of any triangle ABC, b2 is equal to'
```

Of course, you will loose the super script notation. If you need to preserve it, you could do something like this:

```
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> p = Selector(text='<p>For Cosine Rule of any triangle ABC, b<sup>2</sup> is equal to</p>')
>>> t = p.css('p::text, p *')
>>> result = []
>>> for e in t:
...     if type(e.root) is str:
...         result.append(e.root)
...     elif e.root.tag == 'sup':
...         result.append('^' + e.root.text)  # Assuming there can't be more nested elements
...     # handle other tags like sub
...
>>> ''.join(result)
'For Cosine Rule of any triangle ABC, b^2 is equal to'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This works fine when there is only one such question on the page. What would I do if there were multiple such p tags in the page, each which may or may not have a sub element?

Comment: First select all the questions and apply this logic to each individually. Something like `for question in response.css('p.some-class'):`, putting the logic inside the loop. If the questions have descendant elements or not will not affect this approach, which is pretty nice.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I ended up using this in conjunction with checking the list length. Since I know that there are only 5 per page, I only ran these then.